# C preprocessor conditional statement output

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have this code but not able to understand the output. Can someone help out to know the behaviour

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int a =1;
#if(a==0)
  printf("equal");
#else if
  printf("unequal");
#endif

return -1;
}
```

Output comes out to be **`equal`**. Strange for me.

Also if i change the `if` condition to `a==2`, the output comes **`unequal`**

If i try to print value of 'a' inside 'if' block something like

```
#if(a==0)
 printf("value of a: %d",a);
```

output comes out to be **`value of a: 1`**

Please some one explain the output.

Comment: Are you aware what the C preprocessor is and how it functions? I recommend Kernighan, Ritchie, *The C Programming Language*, 2nd ed as required reading for any prospective C programmer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `a` in the preprocessor directive refers to preprocessor definitions, not variables in your program. Since `a` is not `#define`d, its value is effectively `0` for the purposes of `#if`.

Answer (score 3):

The preprocessor directives (the lines starting with `#`) are dealt with at *compile time*, not at runtime.  The `a` in that `#if` is not the same as the `a` variable you declared.  The preprocessor just replaces it with `0`, since there is no `#define a` statement anywhere.  The variable `a` is unused in your program.  If you *do* use it, like in the `printf` statement you show, it will get printed as expected - a value of `1` that you assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int a =1;
#if(a==0)
  printf("equal");
#else if
  printf("unequal");
#endif

return -1;
}
```

which you pass to the compiler will first go through the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) whose output is then sent as an input to the compiler; the preprocessor will send

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

int a =1;
printf("equal");

return -1;
}
```

to the compiler, which is the reason you see `equal` always. The reason is since `a` as a macro is undefined, the first condition is true, there by leading to only passing that statement on to the compiler. If you try adding `#define a 1` next to the include directive, then you'll always see `unequal` as an output; but these changes affect only the compile time macro `a` and not the runtime variable `a` (both are entirely different).

All this because preprocessor is concerned only with compile-time constructs. What you really need may be

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

   int a =1;
   if(a == 0)
     printf("equal");
   else
     printf("unequal");

   return 0;
}
```

**Aside:** Return 0 when you're program is successful, returning negative values from main usually means some error state termination of your program.